# Generating Client Callback Service Interface For WCF

Tags: wcf

HI

I am trying to follow the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx , but i cant seem to generate the Client Callback Interface. I am using VS 2008.

Not sure what is causing it , because 2 separate articles that i tried give the same prob.

Thanks

Comment: @stalkerh: You have to be more specific.  What do you mean you can't seem to generate the interface?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what?  Do you have any source code to show, or information about the process you followed?

Comment: @casperOne i followed the article exactly and i did not get any errors there was just no interface for me to use.

Comment: This is not specific enough.  Did you get any code generated?  Do you see the interface for your service, but not the client callback interface? Did you use an appropriate dual channel binding, like WSDualHttp?

Comment: I got the normal service side code generated just no client side code (Interface) , yes i did use the correct binding

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add CallBackContract named-parameter in ServiceContract attribute. 
eg:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples",SessionMode=SessionMode.Required,
CallbackContract=typeof(ICalculatorDuplexCallback))]
```

I know this post has been submitted about 3 years ago, but for those who still having the same issue.